# How to find a particular exception inside the traceback using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Having a `test_raises` test like this, which checks that `ValueError` was raised using [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/reference.html#pytest-raises):

```py
import pytest


def foo():
    raise RuntimeError("Foo")


def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except RuntimeError:
        raise ValueError("Bar")


def test_raises():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Bar"):
        bar()
```

How can I check within the test that `RuntimeError` was also raised at some point and that it was raised with the `"Foo"` message?

It seems like pytest allows you to `with pytest.raises(ValueError) as exc_info:`, but not sure which is the best way to traverse the [`ExceptionInfo`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/reference.html#_pytest._code.ExceptionInfo) in order to find the `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the [getrepr](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/reference.html#_pytest._code.ExceptionInfo.getrepr) method

```
def test_raises():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Bar") as exc_info:
        bar()

    found = False
    for lst in exc_info.getrepr(style="short").chain:
        for tup in lst:
            if hasattr(tup, "reprentries") and "RuntimeErrors" in str(tup.reprentries):
                found = True
    assert found, "RuntimeError not found in stacktrace"
```

If you know for sure the location of the error you can remove the loops and hardcode the location, something like

```
assert "RuntimeError" in str(exc_info.getrepr(style="short").chain[0][1]), "RuntimeError not found in stacktrace"
```

Comment: Would it be possible to check for the `RuntimeError` class instead of just the string representation? I would be interested in checking both the `RuntimeError` type and its value/message (`"Foo"` in this case).

Comment: @Peque not as far as I can see, the `RuntimeError` is a chained exception, you can't see it outside the stacktrace string.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait a bit in case someone wants to propose a different approach and, otherwise, accept your answer. ^^